# Use https:// as default jboss web server scheme

Tags: web-services, jboss6.x

Current `jBoss` configuration makes web services available both on HTTP (port 7001) and HTTPS(port 7002), `wsdl` contains `soap:address`
    location="http://localhost:7001/my/web/service/url/".
What I want is to force it to show 
    location="httpS://localhost:7002/my/web/service/url/".

Here are some key parts of standalone.xml:

```
<connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http" redirect-port="7002"/>
<connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" enable-lookups="false" secure="true">
    <ssl name="ssl" key-alias="softclub.mobile.banking" password="rmi+ssl" certificate-key-file="../standalone/configuration/jboss.keystore" protocol="TLSv1" verify-client="false"/>
</connector>

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:1.2">
    <modify-wsdl-address>true</modify-wsdl-address>
    <wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host>
    ...
</subsystem>

<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    ...
    <socket-binding name="http" port="7001"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="7002"/>
    ....
 </socket-binding-group>
```

Is it possible?